# Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {nodeType, data, content})

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-server-components

i have a proble displaying the content from contentful to the server component.Everything works fine with no runtime errors but give this error " Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {nodeType, data, content}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead"

I tried converting the values from the api as string but still gives same error.

```
const getPortfolios = async () => {
    const entries = await client.getEntries({ content_type: "portfoliov2" });
    return entries.items; // Access the items array directly
}


const archive = async () => {

    const response = await getPortfolios()
    console.log(response)

    return (
        <div className="flex min-h-screen flex-col items-center justify-between p-24">
            {response.map((portfolio, index) => {
                const { name, description } = portfolio.fields;
                return (
                    <div key={index}>
                        <Table>
                            <TableCaption>A list of your recent invoices.</TableCaption>
                            <TableHeader>
                                <TableRow>
                                    <TableHead className="w-[100px]">name</TableHead>
                                    <TableHead>Description</TableHead>
                                </TableRow>
                            </TableHeader>
                            <TableBody>
                                <TableRow>
                                    <TableCell className="font-medium">{name as string}</TableCell>  {/* Render title directly */}
                                    <TableCell>{description as string}</TableCell>  {/* Render description directly */}
                                </TableRow>
                            </TableBody>
                        </Table>
                    </div>
                );
            })}
        </div>
    );
}

export default archive
```

Answer (score 0):

Can we have more details about the line causing the issue?

My first guess is that `name` or `description` are not string but object. You shouldn't need to cast them to string. It might hide typescript errors.

Comment: This should probably be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be misunderstanding what `description as string` means. It doesn't convert the argument to a string, it just tells Typescript to pretend the argument is a string for the sake of type checking. But if it's an object, it will stay an object at runtime.

Maybe you can try `JSON.stringify(description)` instead, which does convert the object to a string at runtime.